# V8 inherited FunctionTemplate not getting updates to the parent FunctionTemplate

Tags: c++, inheritance, v8

I'm using V8 to add JavaScript support to an application. For various reasons I can't get into, we need the ability to add methods to a FunctionTemplate, and have those methods appear in any FunctionTemplates that already inherit from it.

For example,

```
v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> parent;
v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> child;
child->Inherit(parent);
parent->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(isolate, "someNewMethod", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(...));
```

Unfortunately, what I'm finding is that when the parent is modified, the children only have the methods that were available at the time of the inheritance, and further, even if I tell the child to reinherit from the parent, it still does not gain the new methods.

Even worse, if I have a relationship like:

```
v8::FunctionTemplate parent, firstChild;
firstChild->Inherit(parent);
parent->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(isolate, "newMethod", FunctionTemplate::New(...));
v8::FunctionTemplate secondChild;
secondChild->Inherit(parent);
```

then instances of `secondChild` still only have the `parent` methods that were available at the time that `firstChild` inherited.

From what I can tell, V8 may be aggressively optimizing the inheritance relationship; objects instanced from the child `FunctionTemplate`s do not show a prototype chain, and instead just have the methods bound directly to them.  So, I'm thinking that I need to use `Object::SetPrototype` to do this instead, but every attempt I've made at that either crashes V8, creates a prototype chain where none of the inherited methods are visible, or has the same effective behavior as the `FunctionTemplate::Inherit` case.

What is the accepted, standard mechanism for providing inherited methods in V8 such that native methods can be added to superclasses?

Comment: The v8 documentation is awful. Have you tried viewing the comments in `v8.h`? They can be quite informative.

Comment: @gmbeard I've been through them with a fine-toothed comb, and what comments exist regarding FunctionTemplate and inheritance only make things even muddier... I'm just hoping this is something someone else has come across and knows the should-be-obvious fix/workaround.

Comment: The documentation says that the `Object` instance returned from `secondChild->GetFunction()->NewInstance()` should have `newMethod`. Is that not the case?

Comment: @gmbeard The problem with that is that I need to instance off of an `ObjectTemplate` so that I can set the internal field count first (since it's backed by a native object), and I can't see any way of doing that with `GetFunction()` - so I've been calling `NewInstance()` on the `FunctionTemplate::InstanceTemplate()` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `secondChild->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1)` and then call `secondChild->GetFunction()->NewInstance()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69352/discussion-between-fluffy-and-gmbeard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that once the actual `Function` has been instanced from the `FunctionTemplate`, additional changes to the `FunctionTemplate` are no longer reflected in the derived objects. As such, once a call to `Inherit` or `NewInstance` has occurred, you cannot change the methods attached to the underlying `FunctionTemplate`.

However, there is another way to do this: for every native class, have a `FunctionTemplate` and then instance a proxy `Object` to be used directly in the prototype chain. For example,

```
v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> base_tmpl;
v8::Handle<v8::Object> base_proto = base_tmpl->GetFunction()->NewInstance();
v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> derived_tmpl;
v8::Handle<v8::Object> derived_proto = derived_tmpl->GetFunction()->NewInstance();
derived_proto->SetPrototype(base_proto);

base_proto->Set("methodName", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(...)->GetFunction());
```

Then when you want to instance an object, you do:

```
v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> instance_tmpl;
instance_tmpl->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
v8::Handle<v8::Object> instance = instance_tmpl->NewInstance();
instance->SetInternalField(0, nativeObject);
instance->SetPrototype(derived_proto);
```

Technically you only have to instance the proxy `Object`s, but still having the `FunctionTemplate` allows you to make use of its `SetClassName` (useful for debugging) as well as `Object::FindInstanceInPrototypeChain` (useful for run-time type checking among other things).

Answer (score 0):

My experience seems to differ from yours. I can indeed set methods on the prototype and they're available through inheritance, even when the methods are added after calling `FunctionTemplate::Inherit` on the child.

The full source of my working test is [here](https://gist.github.com/gmbeard/68d8065a3ff2c15d8296) but to summarise …

I created the `parent` class like so …

```
v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> t = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate);
t->SetClassName(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "A_Parent"));
auto proto = t->PrototypeTemplate();
proto->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "methodA"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, MethodACallback));
```

Then the inherited `child` class …

```
v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> t = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate);
t->SetClassName(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "A_Child"));
t->Inherit(parent);
auto proto = parent->PrototypeTemplate();
proto->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "methodB"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, MethodBCallback));
// MethodACallback and MethodBCallback just contain a simple std::cout statement.
```

*(You'll notice here that I'm adding `methodB` after `child` inherits `parent`)*

I then import import the `A_Child` function into the global context …

```
ctx->Global()->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "A_Child"), child->GetFunction());
```

… And compile / run the following script …

```
"use strict";

var c = new A_Child();

c.methodA();
c.methodB();
```

Which outputs …

```
methodA called from [object A_Child]
methodB called from [object A_Child]
```

I'm using v8 4.2.0 and compiling with clang 3.3. Running on OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Interesting. There are several significant differences between how you're actually instancing your objects and how I am, though; for example, my objects are all being instanced on the native side, and I'm instancing off the `InstanceTemplate` because I was unable to add internal data when instancing off the `FunctionTemplate` (per our discussion on chat). That shouldn't make a difference though...